# from what day he will be back

Tags: prepositions

*I am aware that he is on holiday. Can you tell me **from what day** he will be back at the office?*

I am not sure whether the bolded passage is correct. On the Internet, I have not found any match with this construction. I do not want to use "when".

Comment: Why do you not want to use *when*?

Comment: I only want to know whether it sounds natural to a native speaker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t know what your reason is for not using *when*, but it would sound more natural to use *on* rather than *from* in this context. It is understood that if he is back *on* a certain day, he will be at the office *from* that day forward.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply say this:

> Can you tell me the day he will be back at the office?

It drops the *when*, and you don't need to worry about what preposition to use.